# Scroll to a certain index on a horizontal ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter

I was wondering, how can I scroll to a certain index on a ListView?
I wanted to start showing the ListView in the middle.

I think I have to use a controller but I'm not sure how to make it go to that position.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ScrollablePositionedList` which is a widget developed by Google but not the flutter team [scrollable_positioned_list](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/lib/src/scrollable_positioned_list). You will need to specify the `scrollDirection`.

Also there is a package [indexed_list_view](https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view), you can give it a try (I didn't try it).